# Which plugins could replace publish-over-ssh from jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

At the latest jenkins version 2.331, publish-over-ssh has been suspended in conjunction with the publication of a security advisory announcing unresolved security issues.

[Official website notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDgDG.png)

I can not search out the plugin of publish-over-ssh in Jenkins Plugin Manager

Is there any plugins to replace publish-over-ssh?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why, why would post a link to a picture to a website, instead of just poating a link the the website? This is after all why they were invented and called hyperTEXT links and not hyperIMAGE links. I'd post an answer directly, but instead, let me introduce you to [google](http://google.com), it helps you find answers. They are out there.

Comment: I have the same problem that i have searched but in all relativ articles that plugin is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jenkins there is a general **SSH Plugin**. You can try that. The "Publish over SSH" is the old plugin and is deprecated.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh/

When you look under plugins you should find it.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will try it

Comment: 2 vulnerabilities were found on may 17th 2022 regarding the SSH plugin, and they're not fixed yet, so I don't think the SSH plugin is the best recommendation right now. See: https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisory/2022-05-17/#SECURITY-2093

Answer (score 4):

This plugin has been updated and can be used again. See: https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ssh/

It looks like it is no longer listed as deprecated.

Comment: Yes, it has been removed from the suspended plugins list as well. Ref: https://www.jenkins.io/security/plugins/#suspensions